# Is this the correct way to set up google analytics in a rails 5 app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-analytics, coffeescript

There's no shortage of "tutorials" that cover google analytics in Rails, but I can't find one that's actually complete. Can someone please tell me if I have combined the correct information and have what I need to set up GA, and if not, what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

I have made a file called google_analytics.js.coffee, it is in assets/javascript folder. It contains (from http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html):

```
class @GoogleAnalytics

@load: ->

((i, s, o, g, r, a, m) ->
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r
  i[r] = i[r] or ->
    (i[r].q = i[r].q or []).push arguments
    return

  i[r].l = 1 * new Date

  a = s.createElement(o)
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]

  a.async = 1
  a.src = g
  m.parentNode.insertBefore a, m
  return
) window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga'
ga 'create', GoogleAnalytics.analyticsId(), 'auto'

# If Turbolinks is supported, set up a callback to track pageviews on page:change.
# If it isn't supported, just track the pageview now.
if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
  document.addEventListener "page:change", (->
    GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
  ), true
else
  GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()

@trackPageview: (url) ->
unless GoogleAnalytics.isLocalRequest()
  ga 'send',
    hitType: 'pageview'
    page: location.pathname

@isLocalRequest: ->
GoogleAnalytics.documentDomainIncludes "local"

@documentDomainIncludes: (str) ->
document.domain.indexOf(str) isnt -1

@analyticsId: ->
# your google analytics ID(s) here...
'UA-MYIDHERE-X'

GoogleAnalytics.load()
```

Then, since no one ever talks about if this is all that's needed, I used this code from here (https://gist.github.com/esBeee/545653241530f8f2c2e16371bec56f20) and put it in the head of application.html.erb, although that person was piecing together code from a conversation in a forum. His code also says to add a four lines into the google_analytics.js.coffee. Is that an alternative method? An inferior one? Does it require the class @GoogleAnalytics at the top? What's obvious to you veterans is not obvious to the noobs! Anyway here's what I put in my application layout header:

```
<% if Rails.env.production? %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m)
{i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-MYIDHERE-X', 'auto');
</script>
```

Now I have that G_A.js.coffee page of code and the above code, so am I ready to follow these steps to deploy to heroku (came from here: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html)?

```
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "analytics"
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "assets compiled for Heroku"
```

Thank you to anyone who makes proper tutorials that start from the beginning, don't make assumptions, and follow through to the end.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the analytics you get from google and paste it in your layout file. That is how I did and it works just fine.

Comment: and you're using rails 5, deployed via heroku, and did absolutely nothing else?

Comment: I'm using Rails 4 and deployed on Heroku. I used to blog and when you blog, all you have to do is put your Google Analytics code in a div or something inside your layout. Google uses the javascript to run on every page a user visits and that's it. There is nothing overly complicated about it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you provided for the Coffee Script:
http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html

In the Coffee Script code

```
if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
  document.addEventListener "page:change", (->
    GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
  ), true
else
  GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
```

Change the 'page:change' to 'turbolinks:load' which become

```
if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
  document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load", (->
    GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
  ), true
else
  GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
```

Then you are all set. No extra code needed to be add on the layouts/application.html.erb file, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have in my Rails 4 app (deployed on Heroku)
Inside my View > layouts > Application.html.erb :

```
<html>

 <head>
  #meta tags
 </head>

 <body>
  <%= yield %>
  <script>
   # google analytics javascript snippet.
  </script>
 </body>

</html>
```

Google uses the javascript to run on every page a user visits and that's it. As long as you make sure that it is rendered in every page, you should be fine. You could put inside a partial and render it in your layout. Google recommends you put it just before the closing  tag.